# How to add item to mongoose Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a web app that uses mongodb database using mongoose in node.js...
Now, I'm trying to build the rate feature, in this feature, people can rate the store and give some comments about that store.
This is the structure:

```
rate: {
  author: req.body.author,
  text: req.body.text
}
```

To update it I'm using the "findOneAndUpdate" function, but, Always when i do it, the existent rate is overwritten by the new... Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can do. I am just demonstrating with example

Model

```js
//Model
const ratingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: { type: String, required: true },
    text: { type: String, required: true }
});

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    rating: [ratingSchema],
    price: { type: Number, default: 1 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema );
```

Now you can just push a new array

Controller

```js
const ProductModel = require('./models/product');

const { id } = req.params;
const { author, text } = req.body;

PersonModel.update(
    { _id: id }, 
    { $push: { rating: { author, text }} },
    done
);
```

More about: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/array.html#mongoosearray_MongooseArray-push

Comment: Thanks man! I updated your answer using findOneAndUpdate and finally it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

The model

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    rating: [{
       author : String,
       text : String
    }]
    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema );
```

In request handler

```
const Product = require('./models/product');

const { id } = req.params; //product ID
const { author, text } = req.body;

const product = Product.findById(id);

product.rating = [...product.rating,{ author, text }]
product.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is with regular JS, you can simply store the document you want to update in a variable. Then, use the `push` method on the `rate` field before calling `save` on the variable.