# How to add new elements to an array which is a field in a document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with many documents. each document has the fields as shown in the image below.
I need to add new elements in object of the array in content field of the document.
***suppose, I want to add "author_name" as a new element with a value in each array object of field content***. How do I do that?
thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add item to mongoose Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531122/how-to-add-item-to-mongoose-array)

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example in node.js but the mongo syntax is the same

```
async function updateArray(_id, values) {
  const current = await mongo.yourCollection.findOne({_id: mongo.ObjectID(_id)});
  current.content = [...,values];
  await mongo.yourCollection.updateOne({_id: mongo.ObjectID(_id)}, {$set: {content: current.content});
}
```

so the query would be

```
{_id: mongo.ObjectID(_id)}, {$set: {content: current.content}
```